# How to do user authentication when using Socket communication in Android native app?

Tags: android, sockets

I want to ensure all the clients are authenticated and know who they are when communicating with server, how to do that? Any clue?

BTW, can I use twisted on server side, while use socket on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SSLSockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).